# How to get data from db in react without passing it into the state?

Tags: reactjs

I am bulding an e-commerce in order to learn React and Node. I am stuck with the total of the cart since my only solution is to put it into the state. The thing is that the state can be changed with inspect and so if somebody does that it will change the price for an item (So if I click inspect and I select the Cart Component I am able to see the state, click on it and replace any value with the one of my choice).

What I did is (on the backend with node) saving the total into the user model into the db. Now, How can I retrieve it in React?

So, in the backend I am savind the total and into the db looks like this:

```
user: {
      cart: {
           total,
           items: {}
             }
       }
```

I can also send it in a json format into a res like this:

```
return res.status(200).json({ message: 'fetched items', items, email, total });
```

and in the React Component I can retrieve it into the then block after the fetch API call like this:

```
fetch(API end point
// some code with headers and other stuff
.then(res => {
return res.json()
})
.then(resData => {
// here I could get the total like resData.total
})
```

But how do I access to this variable into the render() without passing it into the state and so avoid the fact that somebody could change the state?

If it is not possible, is there any way to get from the db with something like `const user = User.findOne({ email: this.state.email })` and get it like `user.cart.total`?

I have found a few tutorials online but also them they put the total into the state and I really think that it is not the proper way to do so.

If, for some reasons, I am going against stackoverflow policies, please let me know and I ll update my question.

Thank you everybody in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in trying to secure from someone changing the state on the client, if they want they can just avoid using web browser at all and send POST request using postman or other tool and put any value as a `total`. So if you really want to make sure `total` is correct you should validate/calculate that on server and not trust the data that is coming from client.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. That's what I thought and that's why I did save the total into the user model into the db but how can I get it on the client side since I got the Stripe Component in it? I tried with User.findOne ext but it is not working since I think that is only valid with nodejs and also my understanding of your answer is that this also could be changed with other tools

Answer (score 0):

if you are having the issue that you don't know how to pass the total from the db on the client side and you are using the component StripeCheckout just don't use it and do everything on the server side. Stripe docs are very good (apart of this component), here is a link for the docs in order to add stripe from the backend:

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment